# word office-js: get document with CustomXmlParts or custom settings

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I have following szenario:
I have my word document and I added some **settings** or **CustomXmlParts**. I'll send this document to a *Web Service* and the Web Service upload this document to a *document-management-system*.

For this, I need this document include the *settings* or *CustomXmlParts*. When I load the document as **OoXML** the *settings* and *CustomXmlParts* are not included.

But when I saved the document local and loading document, the *settings* and *CustomXmlParts* are available.

I'm happy about every suggestion.

Best Regards,
Denny

**EDIT**:

My result from the `addSync` callback is:
[addSync callback result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhQRp.png)

I think the problem is the `builtin` property is false?

**EDIT 1.1:**

my steps:

1. I set my custom setting in document [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings)
2. I get the word document as *base64* encoded [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word)
3. I save base64 encoded result
4. I insert base64 in new document with [body](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=word-js-preview).insertFileFromBase64().

my problem:

But when I get the **setting** they are `undefined`. I need theese base64 string to send it to a api

**BUT this works:**

when I adding the *setting* and save the word document local and open it again direct in `Word` (after closing `Word`), I my *custom setting* is available.

Comment: What's your callback logging of `addAsync`?

Comment: I edit my question an add my result from "addSync" callback

Comment: We need more detail to help you here.   What do you mean "When I load the document as OOXML"  can you send more detail on your algorith? can you share some code on how you are doing this?

Comment: call `save` ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/word/word.document?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=word-js-1.1#save__ ) in `addAsync` callback ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/office/office.customxmlparts?view=word-js-1.1#addAsync_xml__callback_ ), and then get the document ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word )

Comment: i added `Edit 1.1`. I hope my problem is now understandable